# Ng-change not working properly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using a  input type= number , but  I cannot get my ng-change function to call.

```
<input type="number" name="numero" placeholder="1234 1234 1234 1234" ng-model="card.numero" ng-change="validar_card()" required>
```

my controller

```
$scope.validar_card=function () {
    console.log(card.numero);
  }
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: oks my controller is  simple  only  print a  mensagge,  but not work ...

Comment: please include the html template and more of your controller, so other may better understand and help with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you forgot to put $scope in your console.log:

```
console.log($scope.card.numero);
```

Also dont forget to put `$scope.card = {}` in the beggining of the controller. Below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/5f411u2e/1/

Comment: Check the fiddle, its working. You must be doing something else in your code that it is conflicting with it..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="count" ng-change="change()"  />
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.validar_card=function(){
        $scope.count++;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

With your update, you are not using the `$scope` variable.It should be

```
$scope.validar_card=function () {
    console.log($scope.card.numero);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6WTb/181/)**

Comment: I try   this, but not run

Comment: @MishuLojan you need to use the $scope

Comment: @MishuLojan can i take team viewer to see your code?